# Confirm form resubmission Laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I am redirecting users based on their roles, I changed my `AuthenticatedUsers.php` and added this to the `authenticated` function

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (Auth::user()->priority == 'HI') {
        return view ('dashboard');
    }else{
        return view ('home');
    }
}
```

Now I got it working to redirect based on roles, however when I refresh the page FOR THE FIRST TIME it shows

**CONFIRM FORM RESUBMISSION**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not redirecting the user, you are only rendering a view.

use `redirect` to redirect the user:

```php
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (Auth::user()->priority == 'HI') {
        return redirect('dashboard');
        // with named routes
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    } else {
        return redirect('home');
        // with named routes
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

From the docs:

[Creating Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects#creating-redirects):

> Redirect responses are instances of the
>   Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse class, and contain the proper headers
>   needed to redirect the user to another URL. There are several ways to
>   generate a RedirectResponse instance. The simplest method is to use
>   the global redirect helper:

```php
Route::get('dashboard', function () {
    return redirect('home/dashboard');
});
```

[Redirecting To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects#redirecting-named-routes)

> When you call the redirect helper with no parameters, an instance of
>   Illuminate\Routing\Redirector is returned, allowing you to call any
>   method on the Redirector instance. For example, to generate a
>   RedirectResponse to a named route, you may use the route method:

```php
return redirect()->route('login');
```